# ContentStreamUpdateRequest socket write error when sending large strings

Tags: java, http, solr, solrj

I get the following exception when sending data to solr using the ContentStreamUpdateRequest of SolrJ

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:478)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
    at com.atosworldline.documentarchiver.core.solr.SolrIndexer.addDocument(SolrIndexer.java:48)
    at com.atosworldline.documentarchiver.core.solr.SolrIndexerTest.main(SolrIndexerTest.java:14)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.write(HttpConnection.java:975)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.write(HttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.print(HttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.print(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1644)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequestLine(HttpMethodBase.java:2218)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2059)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:422)
    ... 3 more
```

The reason for that exception is, that I'm sending the binary data of the document to solr. If I remove this, the application runs successfull.
I'm using the following code to send the request

```
SolrServer solrServer = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url);
ContentStreamUpdateRequest request = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest(EXTRACT);
request.addFile(document);

//request.setParam("literal.id", documentName);
request.setAction(ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
byte[] byteContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(document);
String base64encodedFile = Base64.byteArrayToBase64(byteContent, 0, byteContent.length);
request.setParam(SolrDBSchema.DOCUMENT.toString(), base64encodedFile);
request.setParam("literal." + SolrDBSchema.OWNER.toString(), owner);
request.setParam("literal." + SolrDBSchema.VALID.toString(), Boolean.toString(valid));
request.setParam("literal." + SolrDBSchema.DATE.toString(), validFor.toString());
request.setParam("literal." + SolrDBSchema.DOCUMENT_TYPE.toString(), documentType);
solrServer.request(request);
```

I think the String base64encodedFile is to long for a HTTP request, but I don't know a solution for that problem. As far as I know Solr is not able to store the document by configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SolrJ, consider setting the [RequestWriter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Setting_the_RequestWriter) to use the BinaryRequestWriter, like this:

```
   solrServer.setRequestWriter(new BinaryRequestWriter());
```

This will allow you to write your data to Solr in the binary format and may bypass the issue you are experiencing sending the large data stream as XML.

Note that you will need to ensure you have the BinaryUpdateRequestHandler enabled in your solrconfig.xml settings.

```
  <requestHandler name="/update/javabin" class="solr.BinaryUpdateRequestHandler" />
```

Comment: I still get the same exception. I dived into the code. The problem is, that it's hardcoded in the CommonsHttpSolrServer to send the parameters as a HTTP GET request. If I'd able to send them as POST request it wouldn't be a problem. So I should request that as a new feature.